# Can I use my HTTP/SSL certificate for mysql?

Tags: tls, webserver, mysql, sql-server

I would like to know if I can use my SSL certificates that I use on my website (based on nodejs and express) for access to mysql database remotely, or if it is better to create new certificate.

My webserver has access to the database by localost, but I would like to access remotely to change data with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're on the same host, then there's no real harm in re-using the same certificate for mysql administrative access.  There are no cryptographic weaknesses exposed by having two different services present the same certificate.  Since you're on the same host, it doesn't cause you to make extra copies of the private key or move them around, so the key security remains essentially the same.

Just set up phpmyadmin and, assuming you're using Apache to host it, point Apache at the same key and cert already in use by your website.

Comment: My problem persit because I have the server with HTTP/HTTPS website and the database mysql, and I have my laptop with phpmysql. When I log-in with the credentials of the server's databse by my laptop I can access to It whit phpmysql but it say to me that there isn't SSL conneciton. I tried to create new certificate on the server side and put it on mysql database. After that I export to my laptop the client's certificates.

Comment: So your phpmysql is on your laptop, and it's trying to connect to mysql on a server?  Then it's probably complaining you haven't [enabled tls for mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04).